# How to find the remainder of a polynomial with a divisor when the remainders with the factors of its divisors is given?

Tags: polynomials

> $f(z)$ is a complex polynomial, and its remainders with $z^2+z+1$ and $z-1$ are given to be $2wz+w$ and $5-w$ respectively. Given that $z^3-1=(z-1)(z^2+z+1)$ and $w = \frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$, find the remainder when $f(z)$ is divided with $z^3-1$.

My approach to this:

1. $f(z) = (z^2+z+1) \times q_1(z)+(2w z+w)$
2. $f(z) = (z-1) \times q_2(z) + (5-w)$

Replacing $z$ with $w$ and $w^2$ in equation 1 (as roots of $z^2+z+1$ are $w$ and $w^2$), we get:

3. $f(w) = 2wz+w$ and
4. $f(w^2)=2wz+w$

(Basically, applying remainder theorem from teh basics)

Similarly, replacing $z$ with 1 in equation 2, we get:

5. $f(1)=5-w$

However, I'm not able to go any further. Is there any mistake in my approach? And can someone please give me a hint to go forward?

Comment: Seems like you want a polynomial version of the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: @martycohen I don't know the chinese remainder theorem... mind explaining the basic utilities?

Comment: For 3. and 4., did you mean $f(w) = 2w^2 + w$ and $f(w^2) = 2 + w^2$ respectively?

Comment: @AbhigyanC $(2wz +w)$ is a function of $z$, and its evaluation at $z=w$ (respectively $z = w^2$) is given by substituting $w$ (resp $w^2$) where $z$ occurs

Comment: @LucyYang I am very sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that division by $z^3 -1$ gives as remainder a polynomial of degree at most 2, call it $r(z) = az^2 + bz + c$ where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{C}$. Write $$f(z) = (z^3 - 1)q(z) + r(z)$$ Because $1, w, w^2$ are roots of the polynomial $(z^3-1)$ (i.e. substituting any of these numbers into the polynomial gives 0), we have 
$$ f(1) = 5-w =(1^3-1)\cdot q(1) + r(1) = r(1) = a + b + c$$
$$f(w) = 2w^2 + w = r(w) = aw^2 + bw + c $$
$$f(w^2) = 2 + w^2 = r(w^2) = aw^4 + bw^2 + c$$
Can you finish by solving for $a, b, c$?

Comment: Are these sort of questions always solved by finding the remainder polynomial, then finding the values of a,b,c?